# Trying to replace items in a nested list each tick

Tags: list, simulation, netlogo, nested-lists

I am building a model simulating a virus's spread across the world.  I currently have 16 regions, each with 28 variables affecting the spread of the virus.  Due to the large number of variables/regions, I know it is most efficient/best to use lists.

This is my current code for setting up regions:

```
Set Name 0
Set Living-Pop 1
Set Infected-Pop 2
Set Dead-Pop 3
Set Vaccinated-Pop 4
Set Count-Patches 5
Set Density 6
Set Infected-Density 7
Set Development 8
Set Healthcare 9
Set Research-Constant 10
Set Research-Rate 11
Set Water-Constant 12
Set Water-Rate 13
Set Airport-Security 14
Set Border-Security 15
Set Vaccine-Constant 16
Set Vaccine-Rate 17
Set Region-Number 18
Set Airports? 19
Set Hospitals? 20
Set ER? 21
Set Research? 22
Set Water? 23
Set Infected-water? 24
Set Infected? 25
Set Vaccine? 26
Set Borders? 27

set region-data [
[ "Hinterlands"  36138177  0  0  0  2702  13374.60289  0  10  0.975  7.5E-11  0.027103633  0.5  5  0.25  0.03  50000000000  0.007227635  1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "USA"  318433268  0  0  0  1272  250340.6195  0  10  1  7.5E-11  0.238824951  0.5  5  0.25  0.075  50000000000  0.063686654  2  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "Central America"  204157962  0  0  0  383  533049.5091  0  6  0.45  2.5E-11  0.030623694  0.6  3.6  0.4  0.01  50000000000  0.024498955  3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "Andes"  97253901  0  0  0  558  174290.1452  0  5  0.45  2.5E-11  0.012156738  0.2  1  0.3  0.05  50000000000  0.00972539  4  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "Amazon"  186508253  0  0  0  1407  132557.3937  0  6  0.45  1.5E-11  0.016785743  0.35  2.1  0.33  0.03  50000000000  0.02238099  5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "Patagonia"  94307819  0  0  0  481  196066.1518  0  5  0.65  1.5E-11  0.007073086  0.4  2  0.3  0.05  50000000000  0.009430782  6  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "Europe"  742538246  0  0  0  1175  631947.4434  0  10  0.85  2.5E-11  0.185634562  0.5  5  0.1  0.01  50000000000  0.148507649  7  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "Middle East"  209455634  0  0  0  1197  174983.8212  0  5  0.3  1.5E-11  0.015709173  0.1  0.5  0.5  0.5  50000000000  0.020945563  8  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "North Africa"  459321750  0  0  0  2661  172612.4577  0  4  0.2  2.5E-11  0.045932175  0.1  0.4  0.3  0.2  50000000000  0.03674574  9  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "South Africa"  695349014  0  0  0  1535  452996.1003  0  4  0.1  2.5E-11  0.069534901  0.2  0.8  0.3  0.03  50000000000  0.055627921  10  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "Russia"  143538971  0  0  0  4071  35258.89732  0  8  0.5  7.5E-11  0.086123383  0.5  4  0.25  0.03  50000000000  0.022966235  11  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "East Asia"  1510450616  0  0  0  1602  942853.0687  0  7  0.35  6.5E-11  0.68725503  0.7  4.9  0.25  0.075  50000000000  0.211463086  12  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "South Asia"  1674152344  0  0  0  1346  1243798.175  0  5  0.25  3.5E-11  0.29297666  0.8  4  0.3  0.01  50000000000  0.167415234  13  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "Austalia"  23132574  0  0  0  1156  20010.87716  0  9  0.85  5E-11  0.010409658  0.3  2.7  0.25  0  50000000000  0.004163863  14  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "Oceania"  43984482  0  0  0  121  363508.1157  0  2  0.3  5E-12  0.000439845  0.01  0.02  0.25  0  50000000000  0.001759379  15  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE]
[ "Ocean"  0  0  0  0  56542  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  16  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE]
```

In the setup procedure, I want to write a procedure that will select 1 region from the region-data list (with a chooser), and replace Infected? with true and Infected-Pop with a random integer from 1-10.  In my go procedure, I then plan on writing procedures that will set new values for infected-pop, living-pop, and dead-pop each tick, based on the percentage infected, a tbd infection rate, healthcare, development, total density, and infected density.

Before converting to storing data in lists from storing data in patches, I had this code working:

```
to-infect
 ask patches with [infected?][
    if infected-pop < living-pop [
      set infected-pop ((infected-pop + (((((infected-pop / living-pop) * (infection-rate / healthcare)) / development) * ((density - infected-density))) * 10)))  ]
    if infected-pop > living-pop [ set infected-pop living-pop ]
end
```

And will need to find a way to rewrite that code to work with lists.

Is anyone able to help me write a setup procedure to accomplish my goal/help me modify my go procedure for lists rather than patches?

Answer (score 1):

Might be that there are smarter solutions, but you could do something like this:

```
to replace [region var-position new-value]
  let i 0
  foreach region-data
  [
     if item 0 ? = region
     [
       set region-data replace-item i region-data replace-item var-position ? new-value
     ]
    set i (i + 1)
  ]
end
```

The if-condition, checks if the first item of the current sublist of `region-data` is equal to the spcified `region`.
The Command inside of the if-condition is a nested `replace-item` function. The inner one takes the current sublist of `region-data` and replaces the specified `var-position` of the sublist with the specified `new-value`. The outer one than replaces the old sublist in `region-data` with this modified list.
In your case, suppose you have a chooser on your interface named "region-chooser" you could call the replace function druing your setup like this:

```
replace region-chooser Infected? TRUE
replace region-chooser Infected-Pop random 10
```

You could also use this function for any region like this:

```
replace "USA" Water-rate 50
```

Comment: Looks like this would be easier using `map` and `ifelse-value`?